# Can replacing a massive array variable with an empty array cause a crash?

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I'm debugging an issue in Magento where I get a 500 internal service error, and have tracked the problem down to PHP crashing when the program tries to take a variable that contains a massive array and replace it with an empty array:

```
$arrayWithTonsOfData = array();
```

The program fills the array with its own data a few lines later. If I comment out this line, the program runs without a problem.

This confuses me. Does it take extra memory to overwrite a huge array with an empty one, and is this putting the PHP memory usage over the limit?

Edit: Here's the full code that I've marked up with logging statements, and the output in the log. The entire function runs once before the save method is called from the ConfigController, which calls it again. The second call can be seen at the bottom line of the log file, which is also where the program stops.

```
protected function _initStores()
    {
        Mage::log('_initStores called', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_stores   = array();
        Mage::log('Stores set to blank array', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_groups   = array();
        Mage::log('Groups set to blank array', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_website  = null;
        Mage::log('Website set to null', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_websites = array();
        Mage::log('Websites set to blank array', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        Mage::log('Setting model website collection', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        /** @var $websiteCollection Mage_Core_Model_Website */
        $websiteCollection = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()
                ->initCache($this->getCache(), 'app', array(Mage_Core_Model_Website::CACHE_TAG))
                ->setLoadDefault(true);
        Mage::log('Setting model store group collection', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        /** @var $websiteCollection Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group */
        $groupCollection = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->getCollection()
                ->initCache($this->getCache(), 'app', array(Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::CACHE_TAG))
                ->setLoadDefault(true);
        Mage::log('Setting model store collection', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        /** @var $websiteCollection Mage_Core_Model_Store */
        $storeCollection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
            ->initCache($this->getCache(), 'app', array(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG))
            ->setLoadDefault(true);
        Mage::log('_isSingleStore logic', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_isSingleStore = false;
        if ($this->_isSingleStoreAllowed) {
            $this->_isSingleStore = $storeCollection->count() < 3;
        }

        $websiteStores = array();
        $websiteGroups = array();
        $groupStores   = array();
        Mage::log('Before storeCollection foreach', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        foreach ($storeCollection as $store) {
            /** @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
            Mage::log('Initconfigcache', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $store->initConfigCache();
            Mage::log('Setting website', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $store->setWebsite($websiteCollection->getItemById($store->getWebsiteId()));
            Mage::log('Setting group', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $store->setGroup($groupCollection->getItemById($store->getGroupId()));
            Mage::log('Setting place in _stores', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $this->_stores[$store->getId()] = $store;
            $this->_stores[$store->getCode()] = $store;
            Mage::log('Setting place in websitestores', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $websiteStores[$store->getWebsiteId()][$store->getId()] = $store;
            Mage::log('Setting place in groupstores', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $groupStores[$store->getGroupId()][$store->getId()] = $store;

            if (is_null($this->_store) && $store->getId()) {
                $this->_store = $store;
            }
        }
        Mage::log('Before groupCollection foreach', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
            /* @var $group Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group */
            if (!isset($groupStores[$group->getId()])) {
                $groupStores[$group->getId()] = array();
            }
            $group->setStores($groupStores[$group->getId()]);
            $group->setWebsite($websiteCollection->getItemById($group->getWebsiteId()));

            $websiteGroups[$group->getWebsiteId()][$group->getId()] = $group;

            $this->_groups[$group->getId()] = $group;
        }
        Mage::log('Before websiteCollection foreach', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        foreach ($websiteCollection as $website) {
            /* @var $website Mage_Core_Model_Website */
            if (!isset($websiteGroups[$website->getId()])) {
                $websiteGroups[$website->getId()] = array();
            }
            if (!isset($websiteStores[$website->getId()])) {
                $websiteStores[$website->getId()] = array();
            }
            if ($website->getIsDefault()) {
                $this->_website = $website;
            }
            $website->setGroups($websiteGroups[$website->getId()]);
            $website->setStores($websiteStores[$website->getId()]);

            $this->_websites[$website->getId()] = $website;
            $this->_websites[$website->getCode()] = $website;
        }
        Mage::log('End of initstores', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
    }
```

Output:

```
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): _initStores called
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Stores set to blank array
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Groups set to blank array
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Website set to null
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Websites set to blank array
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting model website collection
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting model store group collection
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting model store collection
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): _isSingleStore logic
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Before storeCollection foreach
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Initconfigcache
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting website
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting group
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in _stores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in websitestores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in groupstores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Initconfigcache
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting website
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting group
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in _stores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in websitestores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in groupstores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Initconfigcache
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting website
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting group
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in _stores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in websitestores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in groupstores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Initconfigcache
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting website
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting group
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in _stores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in websitestores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in groupstores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Initconfigcache
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting website
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting group
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in _stores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in websitestores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in groupstores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Initconfigcache
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting website
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting group
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in _stores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in websitestores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in groupstores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Initconfigcache
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting website
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting group
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in _stores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in websitestores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Setting place in groupstores
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Before groupCollection foreach
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Before websiteCollection foreach
2016-09-15T14:39:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): End of initstores
2016-09-15T14:39:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): _initStores called
```

Comment: _"The program fills the array with its own data a few lines later."_ What happens in the few lines in between? Does the logic that fills the array assume it already has some kind of structure? (Also, please include your source code directly in this question instead of linking to another Stack Exchange.)

Comment: It just assumes that $_stores is an array. In the first foreach loop, you can see that it just sets information to the array with an $array[$keyName] = $value construction. I think this is the reason that commenting it removes the problem, since it is overwriting the same data point on the array that point already exists.

Comment: Is it just that PHP is using a low memory limit? What is it set at at the moment? You can use `phpinfo();` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Does the program crash the moment you set the array to empty, or shortly afterwards?

You could try firing PHP's garbage collector first:

```
$arrayWithTonsOfData = null;
gc_collect_cycles();
$arrayWithTonsOfData = array();
```

See here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php

I guess it's also possible that there's more than one variable pointing at the array. That would prevent PHP from freeing up the memory itself.

Comment: What about gc_enable()?

Comment: Using gc_collect_cycles() like that just causes the page to load until I get a "page unresponsive" error. Using gc_enable() first prevents this, but I still get the same internal error.

Comment: The array contains a "store" object, which in Magento contains a lot of different information. That information exists anytime the store object is loaded, which has almost always happened somewhere in the call stack.